# Firefox doesn't display neither hex color codes nor images in the right colors

Tags: web, browser, colors, color-profile, color-management

[image: a screenshot]

Same computer, OS X 10.12.6, Safari 11.0, Firefox 56.0.1

Any ideas? Color profile changes in any way show no effect (like 'Save for Web' in Photoshop with or without embedded profile or with or with put sRGB conversion). And even if, a hex code doesnt have a color profile. What can I do?

Comment: Go to about:config in Firefox and see what `gfx.color_management.mode` value is set too. Here's some documentation about it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/3.5/ICC_color_correction_in_Firefox

Comment: I want to fix it for the common visitor, not just for myself.